# Output variable names when summing a tuple

Tags: python, loops, tuples, combinations

A list of variables with assigned values. I want to return all the possible combinations from each pair (every two of them).

The print-out is the names of the pair, and sum of them.

For example:

```
(Mike, Kate) 7
```

I've tried below. The result comes out, but not the names of pairs:

```
import itertools
    
Mike = 3
Kate = 4
Leo = 5
David = 5

data = [Mike, Kate, Leo, David]

for L in range(0, len(data)+1, 2):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(data, L):
        if len(subset) == 2:
            print (subset,sum(subset))              ---- (3, 4) 7
            # print (''.join(subset),sum(subset))   ---- doesn't work
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Probably using a dict is a better way.

Comment: Simple answer, you cannot. There is no link to the variable name. You would need to use a different data structure (dictionary)

Comment: thank you both for the comment. then I need to consider to change the data structure.

Comment: Your list does not contain variable names, it contains integer values.  There is no link to the source of those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a dict instead of named variables, you can easily convert the names themselves into the int values via dictionary lookups.

```
import itertools
    
data = {
    'Mike': 3,
    'Kate': 4,
    'Leo': 5,
    'David': 5,
}

for subset in itertools.combinations(data, 2):
    print(subset, sum(data[name] for name in subset))
```

```
('Mike', 'Kate') 7
('Mike', 'Leo') 8
('Mike', 'David') 8
('Kate', 'Leo') 9
('Kate', 'David') 9
('Leo', 'David') 10
```